# треугольный бордер в блоке с картинкой

Tags: html, css

Сделал блок (снипет снизу) Но никак не получается перевернуть треугольник наоборот кверху для другого блока.Подскажите как можно сделать,как по примеру на картинке. Пробовал менять бордеры с левых на правые, но получается, что они накладываются друг-на-друга
Вот как хотелось бы 'перевернуть' стиль.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0px; }
  
  body .under-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }
  
     
  body .title-img {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 240px 0 30px;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; }
  body .main-img {
    background-image: url(http://news.mit.edu/sites/mit.edu.newsoffice/files/images/2016/MIT-Earth-Dish_0.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; }
    body .main-img .triangle-holder {
      overflow: hidden;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 325px; }
    body .main-img .triangle-1 {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-bottom: 31vw solid white;
      border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
      float: left; }
    body .main-img .triangle-2 {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-bottom: 31vw solid white;
      border-left: 100vw solid transparent; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      body .main-img .triangle-holder {
        height: 175px !important; } }
```

```html
<div class="main-img">
      <div class="img" >
                <div class="title-img">
          asd sda das
        </div>
        <div class="under-title">
        asdasdsda ad asdas aksdkladakl dkasd as
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="triangle-holder">
        <div class="triangle-1"></div>
        <div class="triangle-2"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0px; }
  
  body .under-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }
  
     
  body .title-img {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 240px 0 30px;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; }
  body .main-img {

width:100%;
position:absolute;

    background-image: url(http://news.mit.edu/sites/mit.edu.newsoffice/files/images/2016/MIT-Earth-Dish_0.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; }
   .triangle-holder {
    
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 137px 310px 0 310px;
border-color: #007bff transparent transparent rgba(88, 67, 67, 0);
position: relative;
top: 137px;
z-index: 999;
overflow: hidden;
height: 0; }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      body .main-img .triangle-holder {
        height: 175px !important; } }
```

```html
 <div class="triangle-holder">
        <div class="triangle-1"></div>
        <div class="triangle-2"></div>
    </div>
<div class="main-img">
      <div class="img" >
                <div class="title-img">
          asd sda das
        </div>
        <div class="under-title">
        asdasdsda ad asdas aksdkladakl dkasd as
        </div>
      </div>

   

    </div>
```

Comment: Браузер завис, первый ответ некорректный был )) 
вы о таком виде? @ddeadlink

Comment: да,я про этот вид) при развернутом экране получается обрезанный вид и вырезанный триугольник хотелось бы сверху

Comment: может я вопрос не правильно понял )
"Но никак не получается перевернуть треугольник наоборот кверху для другого блока"

вам не треугольник надо повернуть на 180 градусов ?

Comment: Извините может неправильно задал вопрос.Получается нужно что бы картинка была вместо фиолетового фона, как на картинке в примере сверху

Comment: я поправил, так верно понял?

Comment: да,все правильно , но как сделать этот триугольник адаптивным, что бы по всей ширине картинки. Просто у вас стили совсем от моих отличаются